# UTF8 строка, в нормальную .NET строку

Tags: c#, .net, строки, кодировка

Я знаю как перекодировать строки, интересует следующее, **какая стандартная кодировка у строк `.NET`**. Пробовал `UTF-32LE`, но символы не правильно отображаются.

> Вопрос не о перекодировании, а о кодировке строк .NET.

[image: Image2]
По просьбе добавлю код:

```
VlcTrackInfo(int id, string name)
{
    _id = id;

    Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
    Encoding utf32 = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-32LE");
    byte[] text = Encoding.Convert(utf8, utf32, utf8.GetBytes(name));
    _name = utf32.GetString(text);
}
```

Если зациклить внимание на том что в `.NET` не важно какая кодировка у строки, то тут думаю стоит внести поправку.

Строка которую я получаю, состоит не из wide символов, а из ansii, которые закодированы в utf8 кодировку для поддержки извлечения wide символов. Т.е. если я к примеру, подключу библиотеку к [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) проекту и буду перекодировать строку там, то при использовании того же `MultiByteToWideChar` с указанием кодировки строки как `CP_UTF8`, я получу читаемую строку (но каким-то образом остается 1 лишний символ). Так же при использовании `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>`, снова получаю нормальную читаемую строку.

На скриншоте видно, что `testStringDotNet` имеет ровно такое же значение, как и принятое функцией входным параметром:

[image: Image2]

**Если я правильно понимаю, то `Encoding.GetBytes` отдает массив байт как `ubyte`, но не `byte` за счет чего и происходит неверное декодирование.**

Comment: не правильно отображаются где?

Comment: Как заполняется поле `name`?

Comment: @Grundy: Конвертированием входной строки `UTF8` в `UTF-32LE`.

Comment: Вместо скриншота, который никак не показывает в чем проблема, приложите код.

Comment: @Zergatul: Вопрос не о перекодировании, а о кодировках строк `.NET`.

Comment: Что не понятного в вопросе? Спрашивается, `какая стандартная кодировка у строк .NET`.

Comment: на самом деле вопрос именно в перекодировании. _Конвертирование входной строки UTF8 в UTF-32LE_ - не нужно. просто присваивай name

Comment: И что ваш код должен делать? Покажите пример, что должно прийти на вход, и что на выход. В .NET не нужно думать о том, как устроены строки.

Comment: @Zergatul: Входная строка имеет кодировку `UTF8`, получается эта строка из неуправляемого кода. Чтобы правильно прочитать строку, ее необходимо перекодировать из `UTF8` в кодировку, которая будет нормально отображаться в `.NET`

Comment: [.NET uses the UTF-16 encoding (represented by the UnicodeEncoding class) to represent characters and strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding) - но тебе это не поможет, так как проблема должна решаться в момент получения `name`, который ты передаешь параметром. Причем ты точно должен знать в какой кодировке ты его получаешь.

Comment: @Yami, в каком виде получается строка из неуправляемого кода? как byte[]?

Comment: String Class [Represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: "Если я правильно понимаю, то Encoding.GetBytes отдает массив байт как ubyte, но не byte за счет чего и происходит неверное декодирование" - нет, вы понимаете неправильно. Неверное декодирование происходит где-то выше, в куске кода, который вы так и не показали. Весь приведенный код и скриншоты не имеют к вашей проблеме никакого отношения. Пожалуйста, покажите код в котором проявляется проблема, а не только свои попытки ее починить.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Слово "кодировка" применимо только при хранении строки как массива байт.  Не может в string лежать UTF8 строка или ASCII строка. Т.к. UTF8 или ASCII, или любая другая кодировки - это то,  как одни и те же  символы записываются в виде разных байт. Но ведь в .net вы работаете с символами, а не с байтами. "A" в utf8 - это тот же символ что "A" в ASCII. Пока строка - это string - вам все равно,  какие там внутри байты.

Нет никакой "стандартной кодировки". Есть строка. Ее можно превратить в представление в виде байт в любой кодировке. Массив байт можно превратить строку,  но для этого нужно указать кодировку для превращения байт в строку.

То,  что вы называете "перекодированием" строки - это костыль,  который обычно применяют для "исправления строки" прочитанной с указанием неверной кодировки. И исправлять это нужно указанием верной кодировки при декодировании оригинального массива байт.

Т.е. код выглядит как

1. Есть массив байт
2. Его преобразовали в строку,  указав неверную кодировку.
3. Где-то ниже по коду делается попытка "перекодировать" испорченную строку.

То,  что получается в 2, вы считаете "строкой в неверной кодировке". И поэтому пытаетесь узнать,  какая же кодировка верная. И исправить неверную на верную в 3.

На самом деле в 2 получилась просто строка. То, что в ней нечитабельный мусор - это последствия того, что вы не угадали с кодировкой при чтении массива байт. И чинить это нужно указанием в 2 той кодировки, в которой строка когда то была в эти байты сохранена.

Т.е. проблема не в "кодировке строки", а в том,  что вы не угадали с кодировкой массива байт том месте,  где из него читается `name`. Вы, скорее всего, читали массив как utf8,  но в байтах была строка в чем-то другом.

Comment: `Вы, скорее всего, читали массив как utf8, но в байтах была строка в чем-то другом. ` Если это так, то почему при перекодировке строки через `MultiByteToWideChar`, с указанием кодировки стоки как `CP_UTF8`, она правильно декодируется. [скриншот](https://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/04/09/0002/2330/141594/94/82671b4b37.png)

Comment: @Yami потому что в плюсах, в отличие от .net, строки - это массивы байт, а MultiByteToWideChar не "перекодирует строку", а меняет формат хранения "строка в массиве байт LPCSTR" в "строка в массиве байт LPWSTR". Даже у вас на скрине видно - у входной и выходной строки *разные типы*, именно для смены типа существует `std::wstring_convert`. И если при смене типа (и формата хранения) неверно указать CodePage - то произойдет "перекодировка". Примерно так же, как если в в .net записать строку в массив байт в одной кодировке, а прочитать из массива - в другой (как в вашем коде из вопроса).

Comment: @Yami  вы сейчас пытаетесь решить проблему "костылем" и "перекодировкой". Вместо этого - покажите то место, где у вас получается битая строка - `name` - из нативного кода. Там фикс на одну строку - правильно кодировку указать (или `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType...)` для параметра, или просто Encoding при чтении из массива), А вы вместо этого пытаетесь "перекодировать".

Comment: Вы правы, когда я скопировал байты в массив, и вызвал `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, то получил правильную строку.

Answer (score 5):

Если вам приходит строка из неуправляемого кода, то принимайте ее как массив байт, а дальше делайте:

```
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: Как это поможет мне понять какая стандартная кодировка у строки `.NET`?

Comment: Как вам это знание поможет принять строку от неуправляемого кода? .NET сам превращает байты в строку, и там всего 2 варианта, Ansi и Wide. Они не имеют никакого отношения к внутренней кодировке строк.